# Having problem in Android Studio, Getting error on gradle Tag Mismatch

Tags: android-studio, gradle

All thing started with Tag Mismatch on Gradle

I tried a lot to find the solution but nothing works, Finnaly I uninstall android studio and downloaded the latest version, and install it again.

After installation they ask for sdk download and then stuck to this screen.
[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b8t75.png)

**Warning: This download could not be finalized from the interim state. Retrying without caching.**

I have uninstalled android studio completely and reinstalled it.

SDK is downloading...

Help me fix this problem.

Comment: try downloading the sdk manually, it is possible both from developer.android and by installing `sdk-command-line-tools`. then install android studio, and just select your previously installed sdk.

Comment: tried from command-line-tools:

Warning: An error occurred while preparing SDK package Android SDK Platform 33: Tag mismatch.

and again got the error Tag mismatch

Comment: Have you found a solution?